# react-native local json file

Tags: android, react-native

Hello I want to parse Json data from a JSON file in local Machine . Here is My code `var data_local = require("../data/StudentList.json");` I want check console what I m getting but I get Network failure can you please give me full example how to get Json parse from local file in React native . Here is my another line of code console `console.log(data_local);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try adding below code:
Your Json code within the "StudentList.json" file will be like this:

```
[{"id": 1,"name": "Student1"}, 
{"id": 2, "name": "Student2"}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "Student3"}, 
{"id": 4, "name": "Student4"}, 
{"id": 5, "name": "Student5"}, 
{"id": 6, "name": "Student6"}, 
{"id": 7, "name": "Student7"}, 
{"id": 8, "name": "Student8"}, 
{"id": 9, "name": "Student9"}, 
{"id": 10, "name": "Student10"}]
```

Your code for accessing json data will be like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import studentList from '../data/StudentList.json';

class DemoApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
           <Text >
             Student List
           </Text>
           <FlatList
             data={studentList}
             showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
             renderItem={({item}) =>
                <View >
                 <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
             }
             keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
           />
        </View>
     );
  }
}

export default DemoApp;
```

Comment: How I use View in Li

Comment: Here my code for local JSON data
 import data_local from "../data/StudentList.json";
 <ul>
        {data_local.map(function(studentData) {
          return (
            <li>
              <View>
                {studentData.Roll} - {studentData.name}
              </View>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>

Comment: @Rifat Murtuza, may I know how do you want to display the data(i.e. possible UI )?

Comment: in <View></View> probalbly it will best for me if you can help me with listview or flatlist

Comment: @Rifat Murtuza, I have updated an answer. Please go through it. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Rifat Murtuza, yes sure. How can I help you?

Comment: I want to update one of my Json file . I add a radiobutton you can see my json file there have a column name status I want to update this from P to A. I have already made radiobutton  P and A Like this var radio_props = [{ label: "P", value: 1 }, { label: "A", value: 0 }]; and  <RadioForm
                radio_props={radio_props}
                initial={0}
                onPress={value => {
                  this.setState({ value: value });
                }}
              /> How I can change status P to A using Post

Answer (score 0):

your json file should look like eg:

**Demo.json**

```
{"name":"Rifat"}
```

import json file in this way

```
import Demo from './demo.json'

console.log(Demo)  //output:  { name: 'Rifat' }
```